# RNFS - Not able to open the excel file saved in download directory

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I am able to save the excel file in Download directory(Android) using the react-native-fs library. But unable to open the file. What to do?

Comment: did you try this library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

Comment: Actually i want to open this file in folder section not via internal app processings. 
I can see the excel file created in Downloads folder but when click it it says can’t open the file.